# Unable to access modules in netbeans; says I need to download JDK

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have been doing a java course from https://java-programming.mooc.fi/ using net beans and the application called tmcbeans it made me download. However, a couple days ago I updated my MAC software to Mac OS Big Sur and I have been getting an error that says

"The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information"

I tried going to the website listed but I was unable to find a link to download the full JDK and I tried downloading through https://netbeans.apache.org/ but I am still recieving the same errror.

Any feedback is helpful, I am very new to coding and would like to get back to it as soon as I can.
Thank you!
[Below is an image of the error I recieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi5Bm.png)

Comment: See [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-users/202011.mbox/<6A5066D1-9B29-4BC2-90B6-259F5E53F6A2@gmail.com>) or [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-users/202011.mbox/<B57FC1D5-7A10-4348-B180-D668FD0C52DE@gradwell.com>) on the NetBeans mailing list (click on the >> on the upper right corner to step through the threads)

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for the thread suggestions! that's exactly the problem i was encountering, however, do you know where im supposed to edit the things as the second thread states? as in the terminal, or by opening and entering that in the tmcbeans app. I really appreciate it!